# How to log all commands on a Linux machine?

Tags: linux, unix, logging

Good morning,
My collegues have created a script that executes compilation commands on UNIX and Linux based machines. In order to execute that script, Eclipse needs to be installed on that machine.

Now I'm faced with a machine where Eclipse can't be installed, my collegues have passed me the results of the compile.log, which looks as follows:

```
g++ <options> ../<filename1.c>
g++ <options> ../<filename2.c>
...
```

Why is this a problem?
Well, "filename1.c" and "filename2.c" are not located in the same directory: while logging the compilation commands, it seems that the compilation commands are logged, but not the "cd 'new directory'" commands, which means that for almost every file (there are more than 6000) I need to find out in which directory they are located.

In order to solve this, I would like to ask my collegues to have the "cd" commands also present in the logfiles, and the best way I can imagine, is simply having all commands in the compile.log.
Therefore I need a configuration, which does the following while entering a command:

```
<prompt> <command_to_execute>
<prompt_result> <command_to_execute>
<prompt_result> <command_result>
```

while currently I have:

```
<prompt> <command_to_execute>
<prompt_result> <command_result>
```

Does anybody know how to get this done? (For all information, the Linux system is a Ubuntu and it's not possible to modify the commands, only the machine on which they are executed)

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the built-in [bash history](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-history-commands-and-expansions-on-a-linux-vps)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using acct `sudo apt-get install acct`. Then use command `lastcomm $USER`. 
Edit
Apologies for being vague @music2myear. The acct package is a process accounting system. The package has the commands ac and lastcomm. lastcomm shows commands logged by the tool for commands previously executed by users on the system. 
Not sure if it will give you specifically what you are looking for but it does seem like you need to look at some sort of auditing tools to track what your users are doing. Here are some links for more information http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Process-Accounting/pasetup.html and http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/Process-Accounting.pdf 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you saying the program ACCT allows for command logging? Perhaps expanding on your answer would make this (and your solution) a little more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply direct the history file to a new extern file with :

> echo $HISTFILE >> output-001.txt

Is this the answer to your question ? Let me know.
The command-line above of course can be used in a script.